# C# Linq .Contains() .Any() .All() with an array of ids on an array of ids

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What I'm trying to accomplish.  I have a table that contains products, a table that contains options, and a table that contains productoptions.

What I'm trying to do is pull products based on variable sets of arrays of options, and I want to return just the products that match those options. Keeping in mind that it may not match all of the available options for the product.

`Any()` seems to work, but it returns all of the products that match a single option, for example gray or square, not gray and square.

`All()` only seems to work when i pass every potential option available in the product options.

`Contains()` produces the same as `Any()`.

Below is what I'm trying to accomplish, and this works if I manually put the id's in, but I have an array of these option id's (and the size changes) and I can't seem to figure out how to make it with an array.

```
var newproducts = (from prod in products
                   where prod.optionids.Any(o => o == 1) &&
                       prod.optionids.Any(o => o == 6) &&
                       prod.optionids.Any(o => o == 4) 
                   select prod);
```

Please help, I can't seem to find another answer.

Comment: would you mind providing some input output scenarios? as simple as they can get...

Comment: Your question is unclear, but If you mean that you have a very complex criteria to filter on, and sometimes you are concerned about certain filter and sometimes you are not. I think you can write a `Method` as a predicate and pass it to `Any()` or `All()`

Comment: `where prod.optionids.All(o => arrOpt.Contains(o)) && ! arrOpt.Any(ao => !prod.optionsids.Contains(ao))`  - i.e. all the options given in optionids must be in the arrOps and not any arrOpt is allowed to be NOT in prod.optionsids.

Comment: I’m essentially working on product facets, similar to a site like Best Buy. So if you're searching laptops, on the left hand side there will be checkboxes for things like brand, memory, processor that you can check off and filter the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach and every product verify if it has options among the expected ones...

```
var products = new[]{
    new {id=1, optionIds = new []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
    new {id=2, optionIds = new []{1, 2, 3, 4}},
    new {id=3, optionIds = new []{1, 2, 3}},
    new {id=4, optionIds = new []{1, 2}},
};

var options = new []{4, 5};

var matchAny = from prod in products
            let found = (from id in prod.optionIds
                         join option in options
                             on id equals option
                         select id).Any()
            where found
            select prod;

output
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4

var matchAll = from prod in products
            let found = options.All(p=>prod.optionIds.Contains(p))
            where found
            select prod;

output
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Edit**

If you are looking after facets, maybe you need to reverse the query, enumerating all the options and project the corresponding counter and associated products

```
var query = from option in options
            let match = from product in products
                    where product.optionIds.Contains(option)
                    select product
            select new
            {
                Option = option,
                Counter = match.Count(),
                Products = match.Select(p=>p.id)
            };


Option Counter Products
4   2   1
        2
5   1   1
```

Comment: I plugged this in and it seems to return all of the products that match including ones that match a single option. I’m trying to exclude products that don’t have all of the selected options. Really appreciate the attempt

Comment: updated the first part with match by all besides match by any

Comment: Oh man this is awesome. Its closer,, Woohoo, but how do I just get the products that have the common options. This separates them and counts the total products with each option?

Comment: i don't think i'm following... what exactly do you need?

Comment: On the first example if you selected option 3,4 the ids would be 1 and 2 only

Comment: well, from what i see you have two options, match by any, and match by all, update your question with an input and an output to better reflect your needs

Comment: If the options were 4 and 5 it would only return I’d 1. Everything seems to be returning 1 and 2 because 4,5 are in I’d 1 and 4 is in I’d 2

Comment: play with this on your side, and i am pretty sure you'll find your way https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/f5f526ada6430044eeebed64b49ec15f#file-stack-47876388-cs

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var newproducts = 
    from prod in products
    where new [] { 1, 6, 4 }.All(x => prod.optionids.Contains(x)) 
    select prod;
```

Comment: This like the answer above returns all of the products with any of the options. Thanks for trying though

Comment: @DClements - Sorry, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @DClements - I mis-read. I've updated my answer. It should work as you want now.

Comment: Thanks!  Everyone has been so helpful!